# Mongojs.ObjectId() produces wrong timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

When create a new ObjectId in my node.js script using:

```
mongojs.ObjectId()
```

I get an _id like

```
“f5818257dd0b55ce321f87b5”
```

When I use:

```
mongojs.ObjectId(“f5818257dd0b55ce321f87b5”).getTimestamp()
```

I get:

```
“Sun Jul 10 2016 19:12:21 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

But when I use `ObjectId("f5818257dd0b55ce321f87b5").getTimestamp()` in the MongoDB Shell I get:

```
ISODate("2100-07-10T12:23:51Z")
```

When I want to sort my documents by `_id` with:

```
db.stores.find().sort({_id: -1})
```

The documents are returned in the wrong order because the timestamp in the `ObjectId` is wrong.

How do I get mongojs to produce `ObjectIds` in the right format ?

I’m really confused, can anyone help me ?

Edit:
When I insert a document with mongojs i get an ObjectId like:

```
“30a282576f9f2c4772e69cd9”
```

When I get the timestamp with:

```
ObjectId("30a282576f9f2c4772e69cd9").getTimestamp()
```

It returns:

```
ISODate("1995-11-09T22:36:07Z")
```

But when I insert a document using the MongoDB Shell i get an ObjectId like:

```
“5782a4809f3c4cbed9f2a8a1”
```

When I get the timestamp from this id using:

```
ObjectId("5782a4809f3c4cbed9f2a8a1").getTimestamp()
```

I get:

```
ISODate("2016-07-10T19:39:44Z")
```

These two documents are created like 5 min apart.
Why is the date in the ObjectId inserted with mongojs wrong ?

Comment: What version of the MongoDB Node.js driver are you using? I can reproduce this incorrect behaviour with the 2.2.0 Node driver (and raised https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-749), but  2.1.21 and older versions seem fine.

Comment: Thanks i was indeed using mongodb 2.2.0 i updated to 2.2.1 and now it's working like expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved I was using version 2.2.0 of the MongoDB Node driver after updating to a newer version everything is working like expected.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really an answer, because I don't know who's at fault or how to properly fix it, but the cause is due to different byte orders.

Taking your `30a282576f9f2c4772e69cd9` example and switching endianness on it (see below) yields `5782a230472c9f6fd99ce672`, which is interpreted correctly in the MongoDB shell.

Here's the code:

```
let buf1 = Buffer.from('30a282576f9f2c4772e69cd9', 'hex');
let buf2 = Buffer.alloc(buf1.length);

[ 0, 4, 8 ].forEach(o => buf2.writeUInt32LE( buf1.readUInt32BE(o, 4), o ));

console.log(buf1.toString('hex'));
console.log(buf2.toString('hex'));
```

I don't think it has to do with mongojs, because that's just using the official MongoDB Node driver.